# What's the geometry of a gravitational field at the flat end of a cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Gauss's law is fairly straightforward in explaining the gravitational field strength around the *curved* sides of a cylinder - but what is the geometry of the field at the flat end?

For example, does it have a curved differential as the field transitions along the flat end (like the image below)?

[image: cylinder]

And does the field become more pronounced as the cylinder lengthens (like the image below)?

[image: longer cylinder]

What equations describe this and are useful for plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss law is useful only in the cases of high symmetry systems like sphere, infinitely long (or very long and thin) cylinder, or infinite plane. You can't even apply it to curved sides of "real", short cylinder. You need to show somehow that gravitational field is the same everywhere on you Gauss surface, so that integral in the Gauss law turns out to be a regular product, and that's not the case here.

The only alternative method to determine the field of an arbitrary body is to use the Newton law (for small bit of body) and integrate, but usually this is arduous.

Comment: Gotcha. When I google "Newtonian gravitational field for irregular shape", the only useful thing I can find is this: http://thescipub.com/PDF/pisp.2012.50.57.pdf. Since I'm more interested in elongated geometry, can I just assume length is `8L` and not `2L`? I can do the rest from there.

Comment: If they are asking you for the field at the flat end, then it is apparent that you should not use Gauss law. For long cylinder you just assume that endpoint surfaces are of negligible size compared to the side.

Comment: Just an FYI the only person asking is me :) This is part of a personal project :) Since the paper I referenced earlier seems to only mention Newtonian gravity (that was also where `2L` was coming from), I'm going to assume I am following your advice correctly. Thanks!